# Is the answer zero?

Tags: complex-integration

My question for my exam on linear algebra was to evaluate the integral  $\displaystyle \oint  \operatorname{im}(z^2)dz$ , where integration is done under area bounded by vertices $0$, $1$, $i$ in the complex plane.

Since $\operatorname{im}(z^2)=2xy$, is the answer $0$?

*EDIT:-
I am posting a picture of the question below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL9LF.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Strange question for a *linear algebra* exam...!

Comment: Why should the integral of $2xy$ be zero ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the paths $[0,1]$ and $[i,0]$, the function is $0$, hence its path integral is too.

On $[1,i]$ we have to compute it. This  path is parametrised by $\begin{cases}x=1-t\\y=t\end{cases}(0\le t\le 1)$, so we just have to compute
$$\int_{[1,i]}\operatorname{im}z^2\,\mathrm d z=\int_0^{1}\!2t(1-t)\, (-1+i)\,\mathrm d t=(-1+i)\biggl[t^2-\frac{2t^3}3\biggr]_0^1=\frac{-1+i}3.$$

Comment: Can you explain the second equality? Where does the $(-1+i)$ come from?

Comment: It is $\dfrac{\mathrm d z}{\mathrm d t} $ for this path.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is $\int _0^{1}\int_0^{x} 2xy \, dy\, dx=1/4$.

Comment: I believe you're mistaken; you've computed the integral over the interior of the triangle, but what's asked for is the path integral over the boundary of the triangle.

Comment: @JohnHughes The phrasing in the question is a little confusing since it asks for both the line integral and the integration done under an area.

Comment: It clearly says integral under the area though the notation does not agree with this. I took his wording as what he wanted.

Comment: Hey, I have now added a picture of the question itself.

Comment: I agree it's confusing; it's somewhat less confusing when you see the original (as is so often the case). In this case, it appears that my guess was the right one, but to be honest, I was about 40% believing that yours was. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that here we are talking about the complex line integral of $\mbox{Im}(z^2)$ **around** the triangle of vertices $0$, $1$, $i$ in the complex plane (counterclockwise?).

Hence, since $\mbox{Im}(z^2)=2xy\not=0$ just on the the segment $S$ from $1$ to $i$, it follows that 
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{C}\mbox{Im}(z^2)dz&=\int_{C}2xyd(x+iy)=2\int_{S}xydx+2i\int_{S}xydy
\\&=2\int_{x=1}^0x(1-x)dx+2i\int_{y=0}^1(1-y)ydy\\&=2(-1+i)\int_{t=0}^1(t-t^2)dt=\frac{-1+i}{3}.\end{align*}$$

Comment: Hey, I have now added a picture of the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing in your question is a little awkward since the question asks for $\oint$, which is a line integral, and states that "where integration is done under area," which sounds like an area integral.

Breaking the triangle into its three edges, we can construct the paths:
\begin{align}
\gamma_1(t)&=t\\
\gamma_2(t)&=(1-t)+ti\\
\gamma_3(t)&=(1-t)i.
\end{align}

Then $\gamma_1$ is the path from $0$ to $1$, $\gamma_2$ is the path from $1$ to $i$, and $\gamma_3$ is the path from $i$ to $0$ (each path has domain $[0,1]$).

Then, since
\begin{align}
\gamma_1'(t)&=1\\
\gamma_2'(t)&=-1+i\\
\gamma_3'(t)&=-i,
\end{align}
we can substitute these into a line integral to get
\begin{align}
\oint\Im(z^2)dz&=\int_0^1 \Im(t^2)\cdot 1dt\\&+\int_0^1 \Im(((1-t)+ti)^2)\cdot(-1+i)dt+\int_0^1\Im(((1-t)i)^2)\cdot(-1)dt
\end{align}
In the first and third integrals, the argument to $\Im$ is real, so the integrand in these cases is $0$.  This leaves the second integral:
$$
\int_0^1 \Im(((1-t)+ti)^2)\cdot(-1+i)dt=(-1+i)\int_0^1\Im((1-2t)+2t(1-t)i)dt.
$$
We can simplify this to
$$
(-1+i)\int_0^12t(1-t)dt=2(-1+i)\left.\left(\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{t^3}{3}\right)\right|_0^1=2(-1+i)\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}(-1+i).
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is ***general complex integration***. Realy strange question for a linear algebra exam !!  [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2838360/573334) answer is right.